# Is the passive constructed correctly: "The city will have been being locked down for 15 days from tomorrow"?

Tags: passive-voice, present-perfect, future, future-perfect

That is what I learned from grammar books.

1. "**I go to the cinema tomorrow**" means I am scheduled to go there at that fixed time
2. “**I am going to the movies tomorrow**” means I bought the ticket (ie I arranged it)
3. “**I am going to go to the movies tomorrow**” means I am planning to go to the movies but I have not bought any ticket.
4. “**I will go to the movies tomorrow**” means right now I suddenly have that intention of going to the movies (this is a spontaneous decision at the time of speaking)

Today is the 1st of May and the city council announced the city will be locked down from the 2nd of May to the 16th of May.

Is it correct to say

5. “The city **will have been being** locked down for 15 days from tomorrow.” (is it like a prediction?)
6. “The city **will have been** in lockdown for 15 days from tomorrow.” (is it like a prediction?)
7. “The city **is in lockdown** for 15 days from tomorrow." (is this  like a future scheduled event?)
8. “The city **is being locked down** for 15 days from tomorrow.” (is this like a future arrangement?)

Comment: The city will be locked down for 15 days beginning tomorrow. Or as of tomorrow.

Comment: Fifteen days from tomorrow sure is a funny way to say sixteen days. :)

Comment: I'm marking this as a duplicate because [Robusto's answer](https://english.stackexchange.com/a/21847/18696) answers this. You're talking about a point in the future (16 May) and assessing a period up to then, from a point that's still in the future at the moment (2 May). "On 16 May, the city will have been in lockdown for 15 days". Your difficulty is when including "from tomorrow" as that fixes the reference point and then looks **forward** from that point to a date **further** in the future: "The city will be in lockdown for 15 days from tomorrow".

Comment: Having said that, there are several ways of expressing the future: "is in lockdown" and "is being locked down" work just as well as "will be in lockdown". The point is that you can't use "will have been" when you're assessing a period in the future of your reference point.

Comment: Many of those example sentences are ungrammatical. And most of the 'Cinema' ones do not necessarily match the descriptions, in common speech all three are synonymous.  Of the others, only number 7 describes the situation you've set out.

Comment: @Mari-LouA Use of the passive does not change how the tense of the verb is assessed. I don't believe "will have been being" fits anywhere.

Comment: @AndrewLeach *I don't believe "will have been being" fits anywhere.* Where would  the OP understand that? From your comment or from Robusto's infographic? Here you have an English language problem, nothing to do with SWR or style, but about language and it gets closed as a duplicate when that older question is about how the different tenses relate to each other. The OP's focused on the future, they have written four sentences and they're unsure which one fits best or if their understanding matches the meaning.

Comment: Well, I suppose you could say "On 16 May I will have been being King for 15 days", but that's far more likely to be stated as "On 16 May I will have been King for 15 days". But there's still the issue of reference points, which **is** addressed in my comments and the infographic.

Comment: Your understanding of No. 3 is mistaken, it means the speaker's **decision** to visit the cinema **was made in the past**. The speaker may or may not have bought/reserved/booked a ticket, we don't know. To say "**I had the intention**" suggests that the speaker has since changed their mind and will no longer see the movie. **No 5 is ungrammatical**. It might be best to begin all the examples with "Starting from tomorrow the city....” I don't think Robusto's answer is at all helpful in this situation, it clarifies very little, if anything. This isn't a duplicate, so I'm casting my reopen vote.

Comment: No. 3 does not mean the decision was made in the past.  One could stand up and exclaim "I'm going to go to the cinema tomorrow!" having just decided.

Comment: @Mari-LouA, I did not use the word correctly. "I am going to go to the cinema" means "I am planning to go there but I have not bought a ticket" or "I have made that plan but not yet bought the ticket".

Comment: @AndrewLeach, you assume that just knowing all the tense formulas, I can use all the tenses correctly? How could that be possible? Like math? This is English not math. It's also the meaning of the verbs as well and whether that verb is allowed to use that tense or not. I would give you a Nobel prize if you could make a student use all the tenses correctly by just learning the formula

Comment: @Tom As far as "will have been" is concerned, which is what your question is about, Yes. It's in the linked answer and my comments. While there are bound to be a few specific anomalies, the vast majority of cases (including yours) are answered there, and as I explained the issue you have is using "tomorrow" as your reference point.

Comment: @JeffUK of course it doesn't exclude that usage, practically every sentence that refers to the future  could be said with "will" or "going to" but *often* the "going to" construction expresses a desire or decision that was not decided at that split moment but sometime in the past , e.g. "She's going to move house in the spring."

Comment: Sorry Tom, the question has been reviewed (in mere minutes) and 3 users have cast their vote to keep it closed because it's a duplicate. I totally disagree. Robusto's answer is an infographic, clever, useful if you're just starting as a  teacher but if it were that good someone would have copied and used it in students' coursebooks and grammar guide books by now.

Comment: @AndrewLeach only Jon Purdy's answer offers constructive help to the OP but it is diluted because Robusto's question is much too broad (Hmmm... maybe that should be closed because it lacks focus and detail!) Purdy's answer only touches the surface where the **usage**of different future expressions are concerned.

Comment: @AndrewLeach, instead of saying  "On 16 May, the city will have been in lockdown for 15 days", it's better to say  "By 16 May, the city will have been in lockdown for 15 days". "By" not "On"

Comment: @Tom You could also say "By yesterday/tomorrow/last June, the city will have been in lockdown for a fortnight already." Trying to call *will have + **past participle*** a future something is problematic in many scenarios. It's far more connected to the past due to the past participle. The modal verb *will* is here used in an epistemic mode for saying you're pretty sure that that happened for sure.